# What Tool / App To Use For Running Django Function Periodically (Once A Day)?

Tags: python, django

Can you please recommend an app or a tool for Django 2.2 to run a function periodically? I have a list of products and want to update their price once a day. I've heard about Celery, but maybe there is something  more simple that I can use? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Celery to run periodic tasks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) is relatively straightforward.

If you don't want to use Celery at all, you could write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) and invoke it periodically via a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use celery.

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
"update-task-on-mathmod.org": {
    "task": "project.app1.tasks.task_that_run_daily",
    "schedule": crontab(minute=0, hour=0),  # execute daily at midnight

}
}
```

And in tasks file

```
@shared_task()
def task_that_run_daily():
    print(".......running once a day.......")
```